# Inverse SNR: find the first point with a specified SNR ratio where noise and signal are simple normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, signal-processing

I have a pair of 2 simple normal distributions for noise and signal , specified by $\mu1,\sigma1$ and $\mu2,\sigma2$, so I know how to calculate CDF1, CDF2 for every point.

I would like to find $x$ = the leftmost point where $\frac{CDF1(x)}{CDF2(x)}=P$ where P is a constant desired SNR ratio, say P=3.

I have a file with some several thousands of such normal distribution pairs, so best would be if there could be some Excel formula I could use for each such pair, getting its relevant $x$.

Is there an anlytical solution I'm missing? If there's none, can you point me to some nice way to do it with R/python without resulting to some monstrous "goal seek" Excel simulation?

Thanks! (Math and signal processing novice, be patient)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$\frac{CDF_1(x)}{CDF_2(x)} = P.$$

We have $$CDF(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left[1 + erf\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dx}CDF(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma 2\sqrt{2}} e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$

Using the above two equations, write
$$CDF_1(x) = P \times CDF_2(x)$$.

Differentiate on both sides with respect to $x$ and solve the ratio of exponentials using the log function. You should be getting a closed form expression for $x$.

Comment: cool! so what you're saying is that the derivative is the normal density function. So what I'm looking for is simply the point where the ratio between the 2 normal densities is P?

Comment: Precisely. And that is a linear function of $x$.

Comment: I'm sorry - I must be missing something because I checked it up on Excel and it is not true that in each point X the ratio between the CDFs is the same as the ratio between the densities... did I mess up with the derivation?

Comment: I have made a mistake in this answer. I am looking for where I have gone wrong. Sorry to have wasted your time.